# Continuous integration with external references

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm using continuous intergration with TeamCity and my msbuild breaks and errors out on compiling.

I have an external reference that I'm calling and added to VS 2010 as a reference but the msbuild fails and I get this error:

```
[Csc] matrix\MatrixHandler.cs(5, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Extreme' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

[16:49:21]

How do I get around it?

Comment: You could create a library folder in your project and add the dll. Then make your reference point at it.

Comment: so I add Library/Extreme.Numerics.dll to my project. The project is a sql assembly project and I'm using VS 2010. How do I get my code to point to it now?

Comment: Delete the old reference. Then choose add reference and use the browse option to navigate to the location of the dll. The dll will now be part of your project and a build should include it in the output.

Comment: add reference only has Project and SQL Server, no browse method.

Comment: its a sql server project so you can only get it from another project or sql server

Comment: I just created a new SQL Server Project and when I choose add reference I get 2 tabs. One is project and the other is browse.

Comment: hmm i get Project and SQL Server

Comment: You must be doing a Visual C# SQL CLR Database Project. I don't know the answer to how to get around your issue in that case.

Comment: yes its a visual C# sql clr database project indeed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19790/discussion-between-lee-o-and-chris)

Comment: i can continue it in chat if you want